# HTML - How do I make my website show up on different screen sizes perfectly?

Tags: html, css

Currently, my website has not been looking all that great. So here's my issue:

I have created some basic and simple code, (Note: this code uses margins. I am not sure if this is an issue or not) but it aligns accordingly to the screen size, which doesn't look all that great. Try running this code through your browser to see what I mean:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-
wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Portal</title>

</head>
<body>

<nav>
        <ul>
            <h3 style="margin:15px;" class="logo">ONECLICKLEARN</h3>
            <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlink" href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Templates</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlink" href="/css-library">CSS Library</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Updates</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


  <div class="content-left">
       <h1>Ocelot <strong class="tag-greentheme">1.0</strong></h1>
       <h3 class="margin-para">Okay, let's get things straight: you're going 
to get tired of clicking every single download button if you want 
<em>all</em> 
our libraries. So we came up with a little something that just might 
brighten 
your day a little. We call it <em>Ocelot</em>. Ocelot is our main library 
that 
rolls ever single library we have rolled into one. So clear your storage 
space, 
and get ready for <em>ocelot!</em> - Current version: 1.0.</h3>
       <hr>

        </div>


  <div class="details">
        <h1>GET OCELOT</h1>
        <button class="button-greentheme">MORE INFO</button> <button 
class="button-graytheme">SAFE LINK IT!</button>
    </div>

<div class="content-left">
       <h1>Bibrary <strong class="tag-greentheme">1.0</strong></h1>
       <h3 class="margin-para">A new CSS library has <em>just</em> come out! 
It's the first CSS library to be done by this website. The name is Bibrary. 
This handy library covers all the buttons you could want, but remember - not 
all buttons are covered, but be sure to watch this one. It could be updated 
as much as 5 times a year!</h3>
        </div>


  <div class="details">
        <h1>GET BIBRARY</h1>
        <button class="button-greentheme">MORE INFO</button> <button 
href="/bibrary" class="button-graytheme">SAFE LINK IT!</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a margin-left:30px; as well as right 30px;
PLease give a reason if you DO thumbs down

Comment: you are looking for responsive design. You can use a responsive framework or you can build you own

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap Framework. They're the most popular and used responsive framework, you can check getbootstrap.com. Theres a lot of good tutorials at youtube for Bootstrap.

If you want the no-framework way, you can use `@media` with pure CSS. You can read a lot of documentation by using google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries in the css file.
sample syntax here:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Portal</title>

<style>
.content{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>


   </head>
   <body>

         <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand logo"  href="#">ONECLICKLEARN</a>
               </div>
               <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a class="navlink" href="#">About</a></li>
                     <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Templates</a></li>
                     <li><a class="navlink" href="/css-library">CSS Library</a></li>
                     <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Updates</a></li>
                     <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>            
            </div>          
         </nav>
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-12 content">
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 content-left">
                  <h1>Ocelot <strong class="tag-greentheme">1.0</strong></h1>
                  <h3 class="margin-para">Okay, let's get things straight: you're going 
                     to get tired of clicking every single download button if you want 
                     <em>all</em> 
                     our libraries. So we came up with a little something that just might 
                     brighten 
                     your day a little. We call it <em>Ocelot</em>. Ocelot is our main library 
                     that 
                     rolls ever single library we have rolled into one. So clear your storage 
                     space, 
                     and get ready for <em>ocelot!</em> - Current version: 1.0.
                  </h3>

               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 details">
                  <h1>GET OCELOT</h1>
                  <button class="button-greentheme">MORE INFO</button> <button 
                     class="button-graytheme">SAFE LINK IT!</button>
               </div>

                </div>
               <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 content-left">
                  <h1>Bibrary <strong class="tag-greentheme">1.0</strong></h1>
                  <h3 class="margin-para">A new CSS library has <em>just</em> come out! 
                     It's the first CSS library to be done by this website. The name is Bibrary. 
                     This handy library covers all the buttons you could want, but remember - not 
                     all buttons are covered, but be sure to watch this one. It could be updated 
                     as much as 5 times a year!
                  </h3>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 details">
                  <h1>GET BIBRARY</h1>
                  <button class="button-greentheme">MORE INFO</button> <button 
                     href="/bibrary" class="button-graytheme">SAFE LINK IT!</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

   </body>
</html>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but look at this img in the link. It SHOULD look like the img on the left, but it looks like the right, in which I don't want. https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1wlDpMl-P6lBkOfmwcNFzzyMiQVL7cfqy1vt6icB4wKE/pub?w=960&h=720